# How can I fix the following problem with subsection alignment in table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, amsbook

I am trying to set the depth of the table of contents.

I used

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
```

This actually works fine, almost. The table of contents is showing subsections as well, but these are not pushed *forward* below the dominating section names. The list of sections *and* subsections is aligned to the left with the same margin.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: @Werner, amsbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the values used in `\@tocline` for `\l@subsection`:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\makeatletter
\def\l@subsection{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{2.5pc}{5pc}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The original definition in `amsbook.cls` is

```
\def\l@subsection{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{1pc}{5pc}{}}
```

and the syntax for `\@tocline` is

```
\@tocline{<level>}{<space above>}{<indent from left margin>}{<hang indent>}{<font attributes>}
```

You can adjust the values according to your needs.